# Regex with BoostRegex C++

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

Hi i wish to get the values of the following expression : 
POLYGON(100 20, 30 40, 20 10, 21 21)
Searching POLYGON(100 20, 30 40, 20 10, 21 21)

When i execute the following code i obtains this result :
 
POLYGON(100 20, 30 40, 20 10, 21 21)
 
result = 100 20
 
r2 = 100
 
r2 = 20
 
r2 = , 21 21
 
r2 = 21

size = 7

I don't know why i not obtains the middled values...

Thank for your help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

using namespace std;

void testMatch(const boost::regex &ex, const string st) {
 cout << "Matching " << st << endl;
 if (boost::regex_match(st, ex)) {
  cout << " matches" << endl;
 }
 else {
  cout << " doesn’t match" << endl;
 }
}

void testSearch(const boost::regex &ex, const string st) {
 cout << "Searching " << st << endl;
 string::const_iterator start, end;
 start = st.begin();
 end = st.end();
 boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;
 boost::match_flag_type flags = boost::match_default;
 while(boost::regex_search(start, end, what, ex, flags))
 {
  cout << " " << what.str() << endl;
  cout << " result = " << what[1] << endl;
  cout << " r2 = " << what[2] << endl;
cout << " r2 = " << what[3] << endl;
cout << " r2 = " << what[4] << endl;
cout << " r2 = " << what[5] << endl;
cout << "size = " << what.size() << endl;
  start = what[0].second;
 }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 static const boost::regex ex("POLYGON\\(((\\-?\\d+) (\\-?\\d+))(\\, (\\-?\\d+) (\\-?\\d+))*\\)");
 testSearch(ex, "POLYGON(1 2)");
 testSearch(ex, "POLYGON(-1 2, 3 4)");
 testSearch(ex, "POLYGON(100 20, 30 40, 20 10, 21 21)");
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the result from IRC channel.
The regular expression is :

```
static const boost::regex ex("[\\d\\s]+");
static const boost::regex ex("[\\-\\d\\s]+");
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not a regex expert, but I read your regular expression and it seems to be correct.

[This forum post](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/482587-boostregex-and-boostmatch_results/) appears to be talking about exactly the same thing, where Boost.Regex only returns the last result of a regular expression. Apparently by default Boost only keeps track of the last match of a repetition of matches. However, there is an experimental feature that allows you to change this. [More info here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/regex/doc/captures.html), under "Repeated Captures".

There are 2 other "solutions" though:

1. Use a regex to track the first pair of numbers, then get the substring with that pair removed and do another regex on that substring, until you've got all input.
2. Use [Boost.Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/), it's probably more suited for parsing input than Boost.Regex.